# laravel 4.2 How to check whether any user is logged in multi auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using multiauth with two tables admin_profile and company in Laravel 4.2.

```
public function Login()
{
    $LoginData = Input::except(array('_token'));
    //return $LoginData;
   if (Input::get('username')=='' || Input::get('password')=='') 
   {
     if(!$LoginData['CompanyURL']=='')
        return Redirect::to('')->withInput()->with('Message', 'Enter Username and Password'); 
    else
        return Redirect::to('company/'.$LoginData['CompanyURL'])->withInput()->with('Message', 'Enter Username and Password'); 
   }
    //Admin User
    if($LoginData['CompanyURL']=='')
    {
       if (Auth::admin()->attempt(array_filter($LoginData)))
       {    
            $UserDetails = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();

            if(count($UserDetails)>0)
                return Redirect::intended('home');      

       }
       else
        return Redirect::to('')->withInput()->with('Message', 'UserName or Password Invalid');
    }
    else
    {
        if (Auth::user()->attempt($LoginData))
        {   
            //return $LoginData;
            $CompanyModel = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();

            return Redirect::intended('company/'.$LoginData['CompanyURL'].'/home');
        }
        return Redirect::to('company/'.$LoginData['CompanyURL'])->withInput()->with('Message', 'UserName or Password Invalid');
    }
}
```

But i cannot check whether any user of type admin or company is logged in to open the pages like home page which needs user authentication

How to change this
    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
    {
        Some routes....
    }

Comment: Are you using ollieread/multiauth package or another one ?

Comment: yes i am using  ollieread/multiauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your filters please check example for how to fix it https://gist.github.com/ollieread/8303638

In addition that , if you want to use only one auth filter for common pages there is your solution,

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    $guest = true;
    if (Auth::student()->guest() && Auth::teacher()->guest() && Auth::parent()->guest()){
        $guest = false;
    }
    if(!$guest){
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

I also suggest you to define different type of filters these are very useful for who has permission for routes,

```
    Route::filter('student', function()
    {
      if (!Auth::student()->check() ) // Checks the current user
     {
        return Redirect::to('login');
     }
   });

Route::filter('teacher', function()
{
    if (! Auth::teacher()->check() ) // Checks the current user
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Muharrem Tigdemir